# If X,Y are both bounded and closed, does this imply that X+Y is bounded and closed?

Tags: analysis

Define $X+Y$ to be the set of elements $x+y$, with $x$ in $X$ and $y$ in $Y$. If $X$ and $Y$ are bounded and closed is $X+Y$ bounded and closed?

I think that showing X+Y is bounded is fairly straight forward? We know $X$ and $Y$ are enclosed in a ball centered at zero with radius $r_1$, $r_2$ respectively then $X+Y$ must be enclosed in the ball with radius $r_1+r_2$? But I'm not sure how to show it's closed. Given $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ that converge to $a$ and $b$ respectively then the sequence $(x_n)+(y_n)$ that lies in $X+Y$ has the limit $a+b$ which also lies in $X+Y$. However surely we can't be sure that every sequence in $X+Y$ can be split like this?

The next question asks if $X$ is bounded and closed I have to use the fact $X+Y$ is bounded in the first question, which implies I should use Bolzano Weierstrauss but I can't see how I could use it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that it is straightforward that $X+Y$ is bounded.

In fact, $X+Y$ is also closed:

Let $(u_n)$ a sequence of $X+Y$ elements such that $\lim(u_n) = u$. We want to show that $u \in X+Y$.

We can write $u_n = x_n + y_n$ with $x_n \in X$ and $y_n \in Y$.

Because $X$ is closed and bounded, by B-W theorem there exists a sub-sequence $(x_{\phi(n)})$ such that $\lim(x_{\phi(n)})=x \in X$

$(y_{\phi(n)})$ is a sequence in $Y$ which is closed and bounded so by B-W it has a sub-sequence $y_{\psi(n)}$ such that $\lim(y_{\psi(n)})=y \in Y$

Then $ u = \lim(u_{\psi(n)})= \lim(x_{\psi(n)})+ \lim(y_{\psi(n)}) = x+y \in X+Y$.

Hence, $X+Y$ is closed.

Comment: I don't understand why $u = \lim(u_{\psi(n)})$ ; just because $u_n$ has a converging subsequence doesn't mean it converges to the limit of that subsequence does it?

Comment: I just don't see how having a convergent subsequence helps, what difference would there be if one of or both of X and Y weren't bounded - would X+Y still be closed?

Comment: The assumption is that $\lim(u_n) = u$ (and we have to show that $u \in X+Y$). Hence every sub sequence of $(u_n)$ will converge to $u$.

Comment: You have to use the fact that both X and Y are bounded, otherwise it is possible that X+Y is not closed.

Comment: Ok, so it's not possible for a subsequence to converge to a different limit? Thanks; that kind of makes more sense now I think.

Comment: Yes absolutely ;)